# Spring boot application has multiple instances but only one instance should consume messages from RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am running multiple instances of the same Spring Boot Application, that consume messages from a rabbitMQ queue

I would like only the first consumer to receive messages while the other instances do not and if I stop the first consumer, the second instance should start to consume messages.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, it's a feature in RabbitMQ since 3.8:

**[Single Active Consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer)**

> Single active consumer allows to have only one consumer at a time consuming from a queue and to fail over to another registered consumer in case the active one is cancelled or dies.

[image]